# JavaScript Flow types - Type parameter not bound to return value of function

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to create a function with a type parameter which returns an object with a property which is a function returning that generic type.  The following is reduced to a minimal example.  What incorrect assumptions/syntax mistakes am I making?

```
type chatType = {
  name: string,
}

const cake = <T>(asdf: T) => ({
  pizza: (): T => asdf,
})

cake<chatType>({ name: 'abcde' }).pizza().name
```

The error:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ asdf.js:24:43

Cannot get cake<...>(...).pizza().name because property name is
missing in T [1].

 [1] 21│   pizza: (): T => asdf,
     22│ })
     23│
     24│ cake<chatType>({ name: 'abcde' }).pizza().name
     25│
```

Comment: I don't consider this a solution, but perhaps the inference capabilities are not so strong here by design.  But, adding a return annotation for the outer function seems to do the trick:


type pizzaType<T> = {
  pizza: () => T,
}

const cake = <T>(asdf: T): pizzaType<T> => ({
  pizza: (): T => asdf,
})

Comment: Why is the arg type of `pizza` `T`? It seems like `pizza` is invoked without any parameters.